# Dynamic accuracy with Core Location

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, core-motion

I would like my iOS app to get notified in background whenever user stops (or slows down below some velocity threshold) at a place while maintaining maximum battery life.

The catch is that I don't really care for accuracy when the user is moving but I need as accurate measurement as possible when user stops or walks around the same spot.

There are many Core Location tools available:

- Standard Location Service
- Significant Change Location Service
- Geofencing and Ranging Service
- Integration with Core Motion and M7 Motion Coprocessor

Which one of them should I use? Is there a best practice for what I am attempting to do? Has anybody experience with this sort of stuff? I found [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moves/id509204969?mt=8) which does exactly what I want to incorporate in my app but I'm not permitted to use their API.

I've read the documentation but my case doesn't really fit any of the categories they discuss.

Thanks in advance.
Pete.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS8 there is a new technology that fits what it sounds like you are asking for.  `CLVisit` objects are sent to your app in the background when the user arrives or departs after stopping at a location.  Power consumption is very low with this feature.  You enable it by calling `startMonitoringVisits` on a `CLLocationManager` object.

Comment: That sounds really like what I was hoping for. I will give it a try. :)